# Running react-native run-android builds successfully but stays stuck at Starting the app

Tags: android, bash, react-native

Running my React Native application via the Bash terminal onto the Android emulator builds successfully, but remains stuck at:

```
info Starting the app (adb shell am start -n com.myapp/com.myapp.MainActivity...
```

The Metro Bundler is running, with nothing else on the same port and no errors. The app just never actually loads up into the emulator after a successful build (Pixel 2 XL API 27).

Running directly from Android Studio pushes the app into the emulator no problem and it runs just fine (pressing the green arrow button or hitting Shift+F10). This is happening on a new Windows 10 laptop. Running this same project on another Windows 10 desktop and macOS macbook 2018 this issue does not occur.

I've also let it sit at 'Starting the app' for almost half an hour, and nothing occurs. To note, on the other machines it loads instantly onto the emulator.

The other machine's differences lie in the version of Android Studio installed.

**On working Windows 10 desktop:**

```
Android Studio version 3.1.2
JRE version 1.8.0_152
java version "1.8.0_211"
```

**On working macOS Mojave 10. macbook 13" 2018 macbook:**

```
Android Studio version 3.3.2
JRE version 1.8.0_152
java version "1.8.0_181"
```

**On this Windows 10 laptop where it's NOT working:**

```
Android Studio 3.4.1
JRE version 1.8.0_152
java version "1.8.0_211"
```

This is happening with ***React Native 0.59.8*** which is the latest stable version at the time of this question being posted, with React version 16.8.3. The following command is being run through the bash terminal.

```
react-native run-android
```

The expected output of running the above should be that it loads up into the already-on emulator.

I'm suspecting the difference being in how brand new Android Studio is on this laptop, but downgrading to an older version is not an option. Any suggestions or guidance is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Managed to solve it, had to run through a few steps to get it working. Here's what I did.

With the project open in Visual Studio Code, cd into the android folder and run:

```
./gradlew clean
```

That stops it from getting stuck at 'Starting app' but I then ran into:

```
'adb' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

To fix that, open Environment Variables (hit Windows key, search for 'environment' and click on Edit the system environment variables).
Click on the button that says 'Environment Variables...'.
Under System variables, click 'New...'.

```
Variable name: ANDROID_HOME
Variable value: C:/Users/USER/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk
```

Where USER is whatever your Windows username is.

That fixed the 'adb' error, but I then ran into the metro server error:

```
Unable to load script. Make sure you're either running a Metro server ...
```

Despite closing all terminals, visual studio code, and any node processes this issue persisted. Only after restarting Windows, did this issue go away and running the following worked:

```
react-native run-android
```

That's it. Hopefully it helps another. Basically, needed to clean gradle, add Android studio sdk to environment variables and do a restart. Now it all works.